# DropDown part of the EnumDropDownListFor not styled for bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the new (for ASP.NET MVC 5.1) EnumDropDownListFor function, in a bootstrap-styled page.
The bootstrap style is correctly applied to the control, but when I open the dropdown part, it is not styled at all, for what I can see.

My call is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(..., new { role = "form" }))
{
    ...

    <div class="form-group">
        @(Html.Label("AAA))
        @(Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.MyField, new { @class = "form-control" }))
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Go" class="k-button" />
}
```

and I'm loading the appropriate CSS styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE
Upon request, this is the output of the dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The OP field is required." id="OP" name="OP">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">Text1</option>
    <option value="1">Text2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you place the rendered html code of the dropdown?

Comment: What styling are you expecting? Do you mean like [this link](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)?

Comment: Yes, as you can see there, when you open the dropdown part, the items there (Mustard, Ketchup, Relish) appear like the main part of the control. In my case I get a 'normal' list with normal text.